# Loopback protect nested relations

Tags: node.js, acl, loopback

I am having an issue protecting nested relations. I have three models:

1. User

   - has many `Addresses`
   - has many `Users` through `Contacts`
2. Address

   - belongs to `User`
3. Contacts (User-to-User link table)

   - belongs to `User`
   - has one `User`

A `User` can get their `Address` information:

`/users/{user_id}/address`.

A `User` can also get there `Contacts`:

`/users/{user_id}/contacts`.

**But** a `User` can also get there `Contacts` `Addresses`:

`/users/{user_id}/contacts?filter={"include":"addresses"}`

I would like to restrict the `Addresses` relation to the **$owner**.

---

**Temporary solution:**

for now i am manually checking to see if the owner is the one accessing the relation:

```
Address.observe('access', function restrict(ctx, next) {

  if(_.isObject(ctx.query.where) && ctx.query.where.user_id && ctx.query.where.user_id.inq){
    var id = app.models.user.getCurrentUserId();
    if(validate(ctx.query.where.user_id.inq[0] === id, 'Unauthorization Access', "UNAUTHORIZATION_ACCESS", 403, next)){return;}
  }

  next();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in loopback created to fix it and track all related discussions:
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1362